# FlowField Pathfinding on Large RTS Maps

Tags: algorithm, performance, unity-game-engine, game-physics, path-finding

When building a large map RTS game, my team are experiencing some performance issues regarding pathfinding.

A* is obviously inefficient due to not only janky path finding, but processing costs for large groups of units moving at the same time.

After research, the obvious solution would be to use FlowField pathfinding, the industry standard for RTS games as it stands.

The issue we are now having after creating the base algorithm is that the map is quite large requiring a grid of around 766 x 485. This creates a noticeable processing freeze or lag when computing the flowfield for the units to follow.

Has anybody experienced this before or have any solutions on how to make the flowfields more efficient? I have tried the following:

- Adding flowfields to a list when it is created and referencing later (Works once it has been created, but obviously lags on creation.)
- Processing flowfields before the game is started and referencing the list (Due to the sheer amount of cells, this simply doesn't work.)
- Creating a grid based upon the distance between the furthest selected unit and the destination point (Works for short distances, not if moving from one end of the map to the other).

I was thinking about maybe splitting up the map into multiple flowfields, but I'm trying to work out how I would make them move from field to field.

Any advice on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The grid is quite big for FlowField. Maybe you could applies the idea of HPA* (Hierarchical Pathfinding A*) to the FlowField algorithm. Generally, games tends to generate a (static) graph of (reachable) area that is relatively small (refinement technics are used to make the path short & smooth). This is praticularly good for open maps (ie. without many complex obstacles). In fact, this is quite close to what HPA* does. Note that you will certainly get more attention on gamedev.stackexchange.com for such a question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a bit late answer. Since you have mentioned that this is a large RTS game, then the computation should not be limited to one CPU core. There are a few advice for you to use flowfield more efficiently.

1. Use multithreads to compute new flow fields for each unit moving command
2. Group units, so that all units in same command group share the same flowfield
3. Partition the flowfield grids, so you only have to update any partition that had modification in path (new building/ moving units)
4. Pre baked flowfields grid slot cost:you prebake basic costs of the grids(based on environments or other static values that won't change during the game).
5. Divide, e.g. you have 766 x 485 map, set it as 800 * 500, divide it into 100 * 80 * 50 partitions as stated in advice 3.

   You have a grid of 10 * 10 = 100 slots, create a directed **graph** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) using the a initial flowfield map (without considering any game units), and use A* algorihtm to search the flowfield **grid** before the game begins, so that you know all the connections between partitions.

   For each new flowfield, Build flowfield only with partitions marked by a simple A* search in the **graph**. And then use alternative route if one node of the route given by A* is totally blocked from reaching the next one (mark the node as blocked and do A* again in this **graph**)

6.Cache, save flowfield result from step.5 for further usage (same unit spawning from home and going to the enemy base. Same partition routes.  Invalidate cache if there is any change in the path, and only invalidate the cache of the changed partition first, check if this partition still connects to other sides, then only minor change will be made within the partition only)

7. Runtime late updating the units' command. If the map is large enough. Move the units immediately to the next partition without using the flowfield, (use A* first to search the 10*10 graph to get the next partition). And during this time of movement, in the background, build the flowfield using previous step 1-6. (in fact you only need few milliseconds to do the calculation if optimized properly, then the units changes their route accordingly. Most of the time there is no difference and player won't notice a thing. In the worst case, where we finally have to search all patitions to get the only possible route, it is only the first time there will be any delay, and the cache will minimise the time since it is the only way and the cache will be used repeatitively)
8. Re-do the build process above every once per few seconds for each command group (in the background), just in case anything changes in the middle of the way.

I could get this working with much larger random map (2000*2000) with no fps drop at all.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.